Contour lines vector shpfile to 3D Contour (mesh) generation
I am working with geogrphical data. I am very much new to it. So far I have 2D terrain generation available with the help of QGIS and I have data of contour layers in shapefile which are basically contour lines with elevation data in it for each features. Now I want to transform it to Mesh layer as I want to show the terrain in 3D view. How it is possible to generate 3D contour or hills programmatically from contour lines data (.shp)
